# Cannot create instance of activity from a service library in workflow designer

Tags: visual-studio, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I have created a service library as one of the projects in my solution. It works fine when i run it. Now i created a new workflow console application and added a service reference to the previously created service library from Properties->Add service Reference. After rebuilding, the activity came as a tool in the workflow designer, but as i try to drag it, "Cannot create instance of ServiceName,Resource not found" error pops up

Can someone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

It might be that an import is missing in the designer. On the bottom of the designer is an "imports" tab. Add the namespace that contains your custom library's types and it should allow you to drag the activities.